# User Profile Service Application - Set a value for a custom property in the user profile

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, custom, user-profile-property

In the Manage User Properties section of the User Profile Service Application I can create custom properties in the user's profile. But how can I set values for it using the SharePoint UI?

I don't want to allow the users to change these values but allow administrators to set their values for any user.

I know I can do it programmatically (with or without the `/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx` web service) but is it possible to do it in the UI? If yes, where is this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the 'Allow Users to Edit This Property' is selected, and it'll become available in the Edit Profile screen for users (this is in the Create or Edit Properties window, within the User Profile Service Application).

Comment: What if I want these properties to only be set-up by an administrator, and not allow users to modify them themselves? (I've edited the question - sorry I wasn't clear enough from the beginning)

Comment: Then set the visibility settings to not show on the forms. It should still show up in the Edit User Profile page in the Service App.

Comment: I see no field where to enter a value in the Edit User Profile page.

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted? The field hidden when they want to edit their properties, but available when an administrator accesses the property via the Service Application? Unchecking 'Show on the Edit Details page' will enable this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to leverage the **Manage User Profiles** page when managing the User Profile Service Application.  This page allows you to specifiy an user account and then to make any edits you wish.

With the custom fields I have set up, I am populating them with data from other business LOB systems other than AD.  For instance, we have employee pictures, timekeeper numbers and the like not stored in AD.  All you need is an identifier to talk between AD and these other systems...like an employee ID.

Is this what you were thinking?